# cast Derived*const to Base*const

Tags: c++, constants, static-cast

Edit - Put the question into context a bit more.

Given:

```
struct Base
{
    ...
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
    ...
};
class Alice
{
    Alice(Base *const _a);
    ...
};
class Bob : public Alice
{
    Bob(Derived *const _a);
    ...
};
```

When I try to implement

```
Bob::Bob(Derived *const _d) : Alice(static_cast<Base*const>(_d)) { }
```

it does not work. a `const_cast` doesn't make sense to me as I don't want to change the constness, and I'm not changing what I'm pointing to, so why then does g++ tell me

```
invalid static_cast from type ‘Derived* const’ to type ‘Base* const’
```

? If I leave out the cast, it says

```
no matching function for call to ‘Alice::Alice(Derived* const)’
```

If anyone could shed any light on this It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: If `Derived` actually has `Base` as a base class, then (a) this code should not cause any error (it might cause a warning that the const qualifier on the `static_cast` target doesn't do anything) and (b) you can just assign `_derived_ptr` to `_base_ptr` as Oli suggests.

Comment: I think you have the const on the wrong side: `Base* const x;` Here x is a const pointer to a `standard Base` (i.e. you can't change x). `Base const* x` Here x is a pointer to `const Base` (i.e. the objext pointed at by x is const).

Comment: I actually have the pointers as const, not the objects pointed to. Also, this question is not _completely_ accurate (just to stop me flooding the question with code), because I am using the static cast in the constructor calling it's parents constructor: `SomeClass::SomeClass(Derived *const _d) : SomeBase(static_cast<Base*const>(_d)) {}`

Comment: I changed the question to give it more context. I probably shouldn't have tried to simplify it, after all it's me who's asking for help :(

Comment: Actually, why static_cast, why not dynamic_cast ?

Comment: changing to a dynamic cast tells me: `error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘_d’ (of type ‘struct Derived* const’) to type ‘struct Base* const’ (source is a pointer to incomplete type)`. It's true, I forward declared it. Shame on me.
`

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: I think your point helped the OP solve his problem, but to answer your question, a `dynamic_cast` isn't required because casting from derived to base is always safe and a `static_cast` is sufficient (in fact, a cast isn't even required).

Comment: okay, noted for the cast, my mistake. But it's not required, yes. I wrote that in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that Derived was an incomplete type, i.e. forward declared. I'm afraid I've been giving everyone a hard time :(
The answer popped up when Kiril Kirow proposed using a dynamic-cast, upon which g++ spat out this slightly more helpful error:

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘_d’ (of type ‘struct Derived* const’) to type ‘struct Base* const’ (source is a pointer to incomplete type)
```

Unfortunately, I had forward declared Derived, but I hadn't realized it was relevant, and it was hidden several headers further down, which would have had me posting too much code here. Sorry everyone, but I hope this at least helps somebody else later.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any cast at all.  You have const pointers, not pointers to const objects.  And it's legal to assign the address of a derived object to a pointer-to-base without a cast.

Comment: No cast tells me `no matching function for call to ‘Alice(Derived* const&)’`

Comment: @parallel: You've implicitly declared your constructors private, so `Bob` cannot see `Alice::Alice(Base *)`.  As an aside, noe that you don't need `const` in this context (i.e. function prototypes).

Comment: The compiler should be able to *see* it. Access control does not affect visibility. Yet, the compiler should not be able to *access* it. In cases like that the error message usually looks differently. I suspect that the code is fake.

Comment: @AndreyT: I was using the term "see" colloquially!

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory. What if during derivation you had accidentally forgotten to specify that the derivation is public? In this case it would be private by default and the above conversion would be inaccessible.

Are you sure you wrote

```
class Derived : ***public*** Base {...}
```

?
Or maybe you forgot public? Just a theory...

Comment: I think most likely `Derived` and `Base` are simply unrelated types.

Comment: Derived is declared as: `struct Derived : public Base {...};`

Comment: @Parallel: What compiler are you using?

Comment: And also, names starting in an underscore... I dunno... what if this caused the problem, these are technically banned, aren't they? Or are they reserved only if followed by uppercase? Only wild theories can apply here... :)

Comment: @Armen - there're some conventions to put underscore in the beginning of a variables/methods, that are private. This helps then to be listed at the beginning or at the end of the list with possible choices (when type operator. or operator-> after an object). As I know, it's quite dangerous to have names, starting with double underscore, as most compilers use names, starting with __ (kinda reserved names)

Comment: I changed the question to give it more context. I probably shouldn't have tried to simplify it, after all it's me who's asking for help :(

Comment: @parallel: you have unrelated types `Alice` and `Base`.

Comment: @Alf: And why should they be related?

Comment: @Armen: because the code passes a `Base*` to the `Alice` constructor, which expects an `Alice*`.

Comment: @Armen: dunno, there was an `Alice*` last I looked, at least as reported by my eyes. Currently the code has no problems. And as such there is no question to answer...

Answer (score 1):

This compiles perfectly on g++ 4.4.3, no even warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() {}
};

class Alice
{
public:
    Alice( Base *const _a )
    {
        std::cout << "Alice::Alice" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bob : public Alice
{
public:
    Bob(Derived *const _a) 
        : Alice( static_cast< Base * const >( _a ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Bob::Bob" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived* pDer = new Derived();
    Bob b( pDer );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you to use dynamic_cast in such cases, surround the cast in try-catch block and check if the returned value is not NULL. By the way, you don't really need any cast here.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` makes absolutely no sense here at all. Firstly, there's no need for any cast at all. Secondly, the purpose of `dynamic_cast` is to be used for downcasts and cross-casts. This is an *upcast*. There's no meaningful reason to use `dynamic_cast` for upcasts.

Comment: Okay, noted for static_cast and dynamic_cast. I didn't really know that, thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

You have unrelated types `Alice` and `Base`. Change the `Alice` constructor to take a `Base*`.

By the way, I *suspect* that you have your `const` placements wrong.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I intended the pointers to be const, not the objects pointed to.

Comment: @parallel: It usually doesn't make sense to declare functions that take const parameters, since they are equivalent as declarations to those who take without const. The only difference is in the definition where you can't change the parameter

Answer (score 0):

The only problem here is that `Alice::Alice` is private in `Alice`. `Bob` has no access to `Alice::Alice`.

There are no problems with the cast whatsoever. In fact, you don't need a `static_cast` for it. It should be converted implicitly.

The `static_cast` you currently have is valid, except for a redundant `const` qualifier in the target type. That `const` there simply makes no sense, but it is not an error.

Why your compiler is issuing these bizarre error messages is not clear to me. I suspect that the code you posted is fake.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure (too little context) I think you might have meant **Base const *** and **Derived const ***.

**Base const *** is a pointer to constant Base object. **Base * const** is a constant pointer to modifiable Base object.

Comment: I intended the pointers to be const, not the objects pointed to.